# Rlogind in freebsd

Tags: c, operating-system, system, freebsd, systems-programming

I am working on rlogind in freebsd. 
Code : https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/469891/

I was just wondering why are they using the socket descriptor number 0 in setsockopt and getpeername in lines 167 -181? 
I had one other doubt in line 276. Forkpty is used to fork a child process and then login application is executed in that child process but as i understand forkpty doesnot bring the child process to foreground so how is the login to the remote shell visible to the user?

Comment: What release is this written for? To answer your question exactly, we should include the appropriate inetd entry that's responsible for starting rlogind.

Comment: It was written for freebsd 9 i suppose..But how does it matter. Does using socket number 0 has anything to do with inetd?

Comment: Yes. If a daemon is started by inetd with the `nowait` flag, then when it's started, fd 0 is an open, connected socket that has just `accept`ed a connection from a client.

Comment: Yes the daemon is started by inetd with nowait flag. Can you please elaborate on this or point me to some source to read about it.

Comment: First question: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?inetd(8) "When a connection is found on one of its sockets, it decides what service the socket
     corresponds to, and invokes a program to service the request.  The server
     program is invoked with the service socket as its standard input, output
     and error descriptors." I don't understand your second question, sorry.

Comment: The second question is essentially about forkpty https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=forkpty&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html . Does it fork a new child and sets it as the terminal visible to user? Because in rlogin server code forkpty is used to fork a child and the login to the remote machine is done in the child not in the parent